# No compilation error while using long number in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using a large number `-2147483648` in my program, and then if it is negative I have multiplied by `-1`

eg: `-2147483648 * -1`

Surprisingly I am not getting any positive numbers. So my entire code is not working because this value is large. But the java compiler will catch and say this is a large number, you can't use it here.
Kotlin compiler will allow me to use this large number in my code.

why is this happening? Are my understandings wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The number 2,147,483,648 is larger than the largest `Integer` which is 2,147,483,647.
Since Java does interpret all integer literals as `int`, you do not get a positive result from multiplying `-2147483648 * -1` due to an overflow.

Kotlin, on the other hand, does only interpret values up to 2,147,483,647 as `Int` and above as `Long` ([see here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#integer-types)). This is why the multiplication works in Kotlin without problems.

You can obtain the same result in Java by appending an `L` to indicate that at least one of the numbers is a `long`, or casting at least one of the parameters to `long`, e.g. `-2147483648L * -1` or `-2147483648 * (long) -1`.

Comment: You need to do the same thing in Kotlin in this edge case, because the initial value is (correctly!) interpreted as an ``Int``, but the result of multiplying it by -1 can only fit in a ``Long``, so you need to avoid that Int multiplication one way or the other!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Karsten's answer, the reason it's not working in this specific case is because `-2147483648` is interpreted by Kotlin as an `Int`, since it's within the allowed range for ints (`MIN_VALUE` specifically). But then you multiply it by `-1`, which is *another* `Int`, giving you an `Int` result of `2147483648`

That's one greater than `MAX_VALUE` for `Ints`, so it overflows back around to `-2147483648` (`MIN_VALUE`) and it looks like nothing happened, because your result is the same number you started with.

Basically your start value is interpreted as an `Int`, but the result of this particular multiplication needs to be a `Long`, so you either need to make your start value a `Long` too, or multiply by `-1L`